# ZK Disbale Div,Window,Layout Component?

Tags: zk

I am using **ZK Framework** in my project i have plenty of other component inside a div or Window Component ,Can any one tell me how can i disable a  `Div`  or  `Window`  component in certain condition.As i checked there is no any  `disable`  attribute for these components.

Any other way we can i `disable` a  `Div`  or  `Window` otherwise i have to disable each component inside the  `Div` or  `Window` or  `Layout`

Comment: what do you mean by disabling a div component?

Comment: I mean to say component will be visible in the page but you can not modify anything on that div or Window something like datalist ,button have disable attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a very easy way to disable all components that implement the
[`Disable`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/ext/Disable.html) interface.

```
@Wire("disable")
private List<Disable> allToDisable;

private disableAll(List<Disable> list){
   for(Disable d : list){
       d.setDisabled(true);
   }
}
```

You could edit the path of `@Wire` to fit your needs,
use a method of [`Selectors`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/select/Selectors.html) or any other method
that takes a zk selector path. Just let it end with
`"disable"`, so it should select every Component that
implements the interface.

Comment: You have to know your framework :-D And it is much better to read ;-)

Comment: from which component we have to write disable? and when we we will call disableall method

Comment: Example: `@Wire("#win > disable")` should return all children of the `Component`with id `win` that implement `Disable`. And you have to call `disableAll` at the time you want to disable the component.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no simple way, I would try something like this (found this on google but I remember doing something similar on my last project)

```
public static void disableComponents( AbstractComponent pComponent ) {

  for( Object o : pComponent.getChildren() ) {

     AbstractComponent ac = ( AbstractComponent ) o;

     try {
        Method m = ac.getClass().getMethod( "setDisabled", Boolean.TYPE );
        m.invoke( ac, true );
     } catch( Exception e ) {
     }

     List children = ac.getChildren();
     if( children != null ) {
        disableComponents( ac );
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: hmm it mean i have to create a new component which will extend Div or Window and we will create a new attribute for this which will cll this method

Comment: Can you give a full example how you used in your project?

Comment: no, you just call this method with your DIV(or window or whatever) component as parameter, it will take its childs and try to call setDisabled on each of them, catch block is there because some components(like DIV) will yeld NoSuchMethodException - obviously you cannot disable div, it makes no sense.

Comment: I have to disable all the component inside div or window

Comment: I just dont get why you want to disable some components that cannot be disabled... div is just a container, it has no active behaviour that can be disabled. You can disable inputs, textareas atc. inside your DIV or Window but why would you want to disable for example label component? If you want to hide them that would make some sense but this dont.

Answer (score 1):

We can improve Gatekeeper's (May 16 '13 at 9:22) solution adding the condition "if".
  if (ac instanceof Disable) {  --- code -- }

```
public static void disableComponents( AbstractComponent pComponent ) {
    for( Object o : pComponent.getChildren() ) {
        AbstractComponent ac = ( AbstractComponent ) o;
        try {
            if (ac instanceof Disable) {
                Method m = ac.getClass().getMethod("setDisabled", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.invoke(ac, true);
            }
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List children = ac.getChildren();
        if( children != null ) {
            disableComponents( ac );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [There is other a great solution for solving this task.] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175763/zk-how-to-create-container-in-readonly-mode-window-div-layout/34179167?noredirect=1#comment56142323_34179167). Please look.