# ZK How to create container in readonly mode ( Window Div Layout)?

Tags: zk

I am developing ZK application, which contains few roles.
For role "Guest" I have to to make all components in readonly mode.
So how to create a container ( Window Div Layout)  in readonly mode in ZK application ?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583098/zk-disbale-div-window-layout-component. It might help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This link helped me. It is exactly that I need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583098/zk-disbale-div-window-layout-component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this in MVVM also.

So let's start with the beginning.
You need to wire some components as in [the answer you reffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583098/zk-disbale-div-window-layout-component) :

```
@Wire("disable")
private List<Disable> allToDisable;
private boolean disable;
```

The second thing is, implementing the AfterCompose for disabling and the Init for checking the status.
In normal MVVM you almost never need to use the `@AfterCompose` but when you need to wire for solutions like this, you will need it.

```
@Init
public void init() {
    disable = checkForGuest();
}

 /**
 * This method will launch when all components are created.
 * @param view to wire the components
 */
@AfterCompose
public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
    Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false); // after this your private fields are wired.
    disableAll(disable);
}

private void disableAll(boolean disableStatus){
   for(Disable d : allToDisable) {
       d.setDisabled(disableStatus);
   }
}
```

What you need to know is that @Init is triggered first and after that the AfterCompose is triggered.

### Edit:

That's because the databinding happens after the `@AfterCompose`.
You could add a getter for the `disable` and the the zul :

```
 <checkbox disabled="@load(yourValue or vm.disabled)"/>
```

With this, if 1 of the 2 is true, the checkbox is always disabled.

### Last edit :

While going home from work, I can't let this go like this without a descend solution.
After a good night rest, I have found the solution for you.

```
@AfterCompose
public void afterCompose(@SelectorParam("*") Collection<Component> allToDisable, @ContextParam(ContextType.BINDER)Binder binder) {
    for(Component comp : allToDisable) {
        if (comp instanceof Disable) {
            ((Disable)comp).setDisabled(disable);
            binder.removeBindings(comp, "disabled");
        }
    }
}
```

**Explication : **
While yesterday I didn't test if the `@Wire("disable")` worked or not, I'm not getting that working in ZK Fiddle.
So first of all, I wanted to get rid of the `@Wire` so we use the `@SelectorParam` to do the same and like this we don't need to call the `Selectors`.
I had the same problem using `@Wire` or with `@SelectorParam` that I never had any component in the List.
So now, we just get every component in the view and check if it is an instance of the `Disable` interface, witch is actually the same, like this you could even say not for buttons.
Then the second thing, is just removing the binding of the attribute `disabled` for that Component.
You can do that, by asking the `Binder` from the context with the `@ContextParam` annotation.
At last, we remove the binding by `binder.removeBindings(Component, String);`.
Watch out, not to remove the complete binding with `binder.removeBindings(Component);` because at that moment your bindings for the values are also gone.

[You can check it out in this fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1frru9c/4-disable-all) (I exclude the button by checking for `Textbox` so you could still press the button)

Comment: Unfortunately there is one problem ... It doesn't work for components which already have property "disable". Example:  <checkbox  disabled="@load(-----resut  false -----)"/>
How to solve this problem?  Maybe I should launch method  disableAll(disable)  in other place when all data will be loaded ?

Comment: Yes, this will work. But is there any way to override property "disabled" and don't write condition "-- or vm.disabled --" in each component with property "disable" ?

Comment: You could add it to the getter of `yourobject`. The problem is that @load works later on and is changeable with notifying a change.  Maybe `${}` could help, cause this is static and called before the databinding.

Comment: I do not fully understand what do you mean.
Could you please provide a simple example ?

Comment: http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3kvld74/79-MVVM-Bind-on-the-fly look how the label is done.

Comment: Yes, it a great decision, you are really cool ! Thank you very much. It's exactly what I wanted !
I use this approach `binder.removeBindings(comp);`. It fully fits for me.
I don't know why, but  `binder.removeBindings(comp, "disabled");` doesn't work and a data are continued  binding after that.
But `binder.removeBindings(comp);` works fine.

Comment: One more question ... Why  `binder.removeBindings(comp, "disabled");` doesn't work ?
In some cases I need that this works .
But only works `binder.removeBindings(comp);` .

Comment: maybe version, in the fiddle it works so if you post your version I can check it in fiddle. If you remove the `removeBindings` in the fiddle, the second textbox should be enabled by the binding afterwards. Since versions 5.0.0 the property is `disabled` so it should work normally.

Comment: but if it was me, I should put this code into an abstract ViewModel so all Viewmodels are loaded with code.

Comment: I am using ZK version: 6.5.2

Comment: it should work but you use `@load` in zul right, not `${}` because that is not a MVVM binding.

Comment: But I see that in this example in fiddle ZK version 8.0.0 is used.

Comment: Yes. I've tried  `@load` and `@bind` , but it doesn't work  (((

Comment: try to isolate the problem in a small project, you can send it to me and I'll investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

A container is not the correct place to set the enabled/disabled property. It's a "passive" element containing all sorts of other components.

To enable/disable input, you have to set the property directly at the input components like `textbox`, `combobox`, ... . They usualy have a `disabled` property which has to be set to `true` if the client is in read only mode.

When using MVVM you can shortcut this by binding the disabled property of all components to the same view model property:

```
<zk>
  <window title="Enable/Disable" border="normal" width="600px"
        apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('pkg$.TestVM')" >
        <hbox>
            <vbox>
                 <checkbox label='readonly' checked='@bind(vm.readonly)' />
            </vbox>
            <div>
                 <textbox value='test' disabled='@bind(vm.readonly)' />
                 <checkbox label='test' disabled='@bind(vm.readonly)' />
            </div>
        </hbox>
    </window>
</zk>
```

[Here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1oiuctb/2-SO-34175763) you can find a working example fiddle.

Comment: But what to do if in "Window" component we have a lot of input components ?
I am not sure that it's a good idea to set property "disabled" manually in all input components.
There is a good answer for my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583098/zk-disbale-div-window-layout-component

Comment: That's another solution but requires MVC binding. I wanted to show MVVM. I'm sure there are a lot more ways to do that ;-)

Comment: Yes I agree it's MVC. But can we do similar using MVVM approach ?  But  don't set property "disabled" manually in all input components because there are a lot of work to do.